# Referencing firebase document variables from another document

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to have two separate database collections (`users` and `public-users`). To access/edit documents in the `users` collection, you need to be the owner of the document. However, for a public leaderboard, I want the displayName and uid of each user in the `users` collection to be available for everyone to read. To save me the hassle/chance of error, I'd like to reference the documents `displayName` property (from the `users` collection ) in the `public-users` collection.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not have any way to link the value of a field in a document to another specific field in other document.  You have two options:

1. Duplicate the entire value between the fields in both users and public-users.  You will likely need to keep all the copies up to date if you want any one of them to change.
2. Write client code to read the document from public-users that matches the document from users.  This requires two read operations.  There needs to be enough information in the public-users document to find the matching users document.  It sounds like they could simply have the same document ID.

There is no way to make it any more simple than these options.